# MonoTouch 4.2 does not support System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress() when running on the device (works on the simulator)

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin.ios, aot

I am using **MonoTouch 4.2.1 with MonoDevelop 2.8 Beta 2 and XCode 4**. We are trying to call a .Net web service method through classes generated by the slsvcutil proxy generator.

When testing the app on the iPhone simulator, the code is working and we succeed to connect to the server and send web services requests.

However, when testing the app on a device (iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.5), the app fails to connect to the server when calling System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress() constructor.

**Note that it was working fine with MonoTouch 4.0.7.**

we get the error:

```
Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.Enumerable:FirstOrDefault<System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription>,System.Func`2<System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription, bool>)' while running with --aot-only.
```

**It is the following line that seems to crash:**

```
new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(
      string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "http://{0}:{1}/Dartfish/RemoteControlServices/",
      address, port)));
```

**Error stack:**

```
 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method  
'System.Linq.Enumerable:FirstOrDefault<System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription>,System.Func`2 System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription, bool)' while running with --aot-only.
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetOrCreateOperation (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd, System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi, System.Reflection.MethodInfo serviceMethod, System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute oca, System.Type asyncReturnType, Boolean isCallback, System.Type givenServiceType)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.FillOperationsForInterface (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd, System.Type exactContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, Boolean isCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContractInternal (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, System.Type serviceTypeForCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, System.Type serviceTypeForCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type contractType)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract (System.Type contractType)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ICommandMgr].CreateDescription ()
 m.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ICommandMgr]..ctor (System.Type type) 
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ICommandMgr]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[ICommandMgr].Initialize (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[ICommandMgr]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[ICommandMgr]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) 
at CommandMgrClient..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.
at Dartfish.ViewModel.RemoteControlViewModel.ProxyTransportViewModel.DoCommandMgrOpenAsync (System.String address, Int32 port)
```

It's don't seems to be a compiler issue since compiler option is "Link SDK assemblies only" as it should be. **Someone know how to fix this crash or if is a new MonoTouch limitation/a bug in the last MonoTouch version?**

Comment: I cannot duplicate the issue with a **"new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress (...)"**. Please fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and include a small, self-contained, test case that shows the issue. Thanks

Comment: Bug reported: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1053

Comment: I tried to reinstall MonoTouch 4.2.1 again and it is now working fine.   Sorry for taking your time!

Answer (score 1):

> Someone know how to fix this crash or if is a new MonoTouch
>   limitation/a bug in the last MonoTouch version?

Have you tried the current version and/or contacted the support personal for MonoTouch?  Your only question seems like it would better directed at the support staff at MonoTouch and not here.

Comment: No, but MonoTouch support site recommends to use Stackoverflow :-) . I will do it.